# SectionPagerAdapter doesnt want to work and no reasearch has helped me sofar

Tags: android

This error only appears on my master branch and I have compared it to other branches but cant seem to find the difference. When i click on the error it points me to the place where i declare the sectionspager adapter. Ps im still really new to android this is my first ever app so if im doing this whole thing wrong dont feel bad to correct me

error

```
Error:(89, 13) error: cannot find symbol class SectionsPagerAdapter
```

My main activity looks like this

```
package com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers;


import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;




import android.widget.CompoundButton;
 import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


//Defining Variables
public static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView reslut_photots;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Button btnLogout;
private SharedPreferences preferenceSettings;
private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;


/**
 * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnCamera);
    reslut_photots = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BtnCamera);

    if (!hasCamera()) {
        //click.setEnabled(false);
    }


    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    //Background
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.nature_background);

  /** //Logout button listener en logout
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Logout);
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>(){
                        @Override public void onResult(Status status){
                        }
                    });


        }
    });
   */

    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.item2:

                    return true;
                default:

                    return true;
            }
        }

    });




    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);



}

public boolean hasCamera() {
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}


public void luanchCamera (View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CAPTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        reslut_photots.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }




    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}



@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

            /** @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_birds_you_seen, container, false);
            return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_seed_eating, container, false);
            return rootView;

            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_insect_eeters, container, false);
            return rootView;


            }else {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;

            }

             @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_birds_you_seen, container, false);
             return rootView;
             } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_seed_eating, container, false);
             return rootView;

             } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_insect_eeters, container, false);
             return rootView;


             } else {

             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
             TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
             textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
             return rootView;
             }

             }
             }
             */

        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
                return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {

                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 3;

            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        return "Birds you have seen";
                    case 1:
                        return "Seed-eating";
                    case 2:
                        return "insect eeters";

                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my app gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.madchallenge2016edwindaniel.upbirdwatchers"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `onOptionsItemSelected` methods defined in `MainActivity`. Remove one of those and the class `SectionsPagerAdapter` will be found by the compiler.